# How to push to an array in mongoose

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, postman

I have this code:

```
router.post('/setsuggestions', function(req, res, next){
  if(!req.body.username || !req.body.challengessuggestions){
    return res.status(400).json({message: challengessuggestions});
  }

  var query = { username: req.body.username };
  /*User.findOneAndUpdate(query, { challengessuggestions: req.body.challengessuggestions }, callback = function(response){
    res.json(response);
  });*/
/*
  User.findOneAndUpdate(
    query,
    {$push: {"challengessuggestions": {$oid: req.body.challengessuggestions}}},
    callback = function(response) {
        res.json(response);
    }
    );*/

  User.findOneAndUpdate(
    query,
    {$push: {challengessuggestions: req.body.challengessuggestions}},
    {safe: true, upsert: true},
    function(err, model) {
         res.json(err);
    }
);


});
```

When I postman like this:

[image: Postman config]

I get the following error:

> {   "name": "MongoError",   "message": "exception: The field
>   'challengessuggestions' must be an array but is of type OID in
>   document {_id: ObjectId('56263b910d1a2f1f0077ffae')}",   "errmsg":
>   "exception: The field 'challengessuggestions' must be an array but is
>   of type OID in document {_id: ObjectId('56263b910d1a2f1f0077ffae')}", 
>   "code": 16837,   "ok": 0 }

This is the schema definition of AppUser:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, lowercase: true, unique: true },
    firstname: { type: String},
    lastname: { type: String},
    difficulty: { type: String},
    isstudent: { type: Boolean },
    haschildren: { type: Boolean},
    gender: { type: String },
    email: { type: String, unique: true},
    birthdate: String,
    isdoingchallenges: { type: Boolean },
    challengescompleted: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Challenge' }],
    currentchallenge: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Challenge' },
    challengessuggestions: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Challenge' }],
    hash: String,
    salt: String
});
```

This is the schema definiton of challenge:

```
var Challengeschema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String,  initial: true, required: true, index: true },
    image: { type: Array },
    difficulty: { type: String },
    studentfriendly: { type: Boolean },
    childfriendly: { type: Boolean },
    description: { type: String }
});
```

I'm sending this in the function that calls the api:

> Object {_id: "5631423f8c5ba50300f2b4f6", difficulty: "medium", name:
>   "Probeer 1 van onze recepten.", __v: 0, childfriendly: true…}

This gives me following error:

> D:\Stijn\Documenten\EVA-project-Groep-6\Api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\obj
>   ectid.js:134
>         throw new CastError('ObjectId', value, this.path);
>         ^ Error
>       at MongooseError.CastError (D:\Stijn\Documenten\EVA-project-Groep-6\Api\node
>   _modules\mongoose\lib\error\cast.js:18:16)
>       at ObjectId.cast (D:\Stijn\Documenten\EVA-project-Groep-6\Api\node_modules\m
>   ongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:134:13)
>       at Array.MongooseArray.mixin._cast (D:\Stijn\Documenten\EVA-project-Groep-6\
>   Api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\types\array.js:124:32)
>       at Array.MongooseArray.mixin._mapCast (D:\Stijn\Documenten\EVA-project-Groep
>   -6\Api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\types\array.js:295:17)
>       at Object.map (native)
>       at Array.MongooseArray.mixin.push (D:\Stijn\Documenten\EVA-project-Groep-6\A
>   pi\node_modules\mongoose\lib\types\array.js:308:25)
>       at Query. (D:\Stijn\Documenten\EVA-project-Groep-6\Api\routes\ind ex.js:144:44)
>       at D:\Stijn\Documenten\EVA-project-Groep-6\Api\node_modules\mongoose\node_mo
>   dules\kareem\index.js:177:19
>       at D:\Stijn\Documenten\EVA-project-Groep-6\Api\node_modules\mongoose\node_mo
>   dules\kareem\index.js:109:16
>       at doNTCallback0 (node.js:408:9)
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:337:13) 29 Oct 22:05:38 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starti ng...

How do I solve this?

Comment: Can you show us the schema definitions?

Answer (score 1):

Query the User user using **[`findOne()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOne)** first and use the first found document that's passed to the callback to save the embedded documents with:

```
router.post('/setsuggestions', function(req, res, next){
    if(!req.body.username || !req.body.challengessuggestions){
        return res.status(400).json({message: challengessuggestions});
    }

    var query = { username: req.body.username };

    User.findOne(query, function (err, user){       
        if (err) //throw ...
        if (user) {
            if (user.challengessuggestions && user.challengessuggestions.length) {
                user.challengessuggestions.push(req.body.challengessuggestions);
            }
            else {
                user.challengessuggestions = [req.body.challengessuggestions];
            }

            // save changes
            user.save(function (err) {
                if (!err) {
                    // done ...
                }
            });
        }
    });    
);
```

Comment: How should I test this in postman? using ObjectId("56313a951a99710300d9d13f") as challengessuggestions doesn't work

Comment: You could place logging (`console.log()`) in the logic to see what's being returned.